# Python - Win32com not found when running .py script, but found when using python shell

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, win32com

I'm new to python but not programming, so please bear with me..

I am attempting to write a python script that utilizes the *win32com.client* module but am running into a strange occurrence. If I initialize the python shell in the command prompt and manually type in `import win32com.client`, the command processes just fine and I can use the module with no issues.

However, if i code that import line into the .py file and try to run the file through the command prompt (just by typing *foo.py*) it tells me that the `win32com` module cannot be found.. I have the python27 directory path included in my environment variables as well as my PythonProjects path.

Example Follows:

```
import win32com.client

def foo(): <CODE HERE>
```

Upon execution:

> File C:\PythonProjects\Foo.py, line 1, in 
>    import win32com.client
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'

Thank you in advance for any/all help.

Comment: You might have two different Python versions installed. In command prompt or PowerShell, please show the command you ran just before the `import` line. Simply, how did you initialize the Python shell?

Comment: I simply open the cmd prompt and type "python" and this opens the shell. Then it shows the normal header with version info, etc. and the ">>>" line. Then I enter "import win32com.client" and it displays another ">>>" line. To test the module, I entered 'shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")', then tried shell.SendKeys("A") and this printed an "A" into the python shell, which is what led me to believe it was all working fine.

I hope I understood your reply correctly, and sorry for the delayed response. I'm on call for work and it's been a busy weekend :(

Comment: Is there an easy way to check for multiple installed versions? Mine says Python 2.7.6

Comment: Hmmm...very strange error. How did you create .py script? Does it have a [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script) line at very top? Try running in IDLE? And carefully check module spelling.